# Simplicial Complex as a topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I am new to topological data analysis. I just do not get the idea that a simplicial complex can be considered as a topological space when in the first place, it does not satisfy the definition of a topology.

For example, if the Vertex Set V = {a,b,c,d} and we have a simplicial complex K = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {a,b},  {a,c}, {b,c}, {c,d}, {a,b,c}}. And since arbitrary union of open sets are open, {a,c} $\cup$ {c,d} = {a,c,d} which is obviously not in K,  how come K can be considered as topological space? I don’t know if my question makes sense but thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: Should have used MathJax formatting.

Comment: You are confusing the combinatorial data defining the simplicial complex with the space (its "geometric realization", or at least that's the term with simplicial sets, a generalization of simplicial complexes).  One element sets here are defining points, two element sets are defining line segments, 3 element sets are defining triangles, etc. The condition to be a simplicial complex (that if a set is there, so are its subsets) just says that if you have, for example, a triangle, you have all the sides of the triangle too.

Comment: (continued) So the data is telling you the pieces that are glued together to make your space, which is locally Euclidean most places, and not telling you a set and its topology.

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion here over what the topological space associated to the combinatorial data of a simplicial complex actually is.  Suppose our vertex set is finite, say $\{a,b,c,d\}$  Consider a vector space spanned by vectors corresponding to those vertices, say $v_a, v_b, v_c$, and $v_d$.  Associated to any subset $S$ of the vertex set, we can define the open simplex $V_S=\{\sum_{\alpha \in S} x_\alpha v_\alpha \mid 0<x_\alpha<1, \sum_{\alpha\in S} x_\alpha=1\}$.  This is just an algebraic way of expressing the (interior of the) smallest convex set that contains all the vertices.  If we had $\leq$ instead of $<$, this would give us the whole convex set instead of its interior.

Now, for every subset in your simplicial complex, you associate the geometric simplex in Euclidean space, and you take the union of all of them, together with the single points corresponding to the vertices (as the open simplices were empty). This is a subspace of Euclidean space, and inherits the subspace topology.

The condition to be a simplicial complex, namely that we are downward closed, says that if we have a simplex, then we have its face, and is essentially saying that we are the union of closed simplices.

Comment: If you used closed simplices (with inequality $0 \le x_\alpha \le 1$) instead of open simplices, you would not need to treat vertices in an exceptional way.

Comment: @LeeMosher that is true, but then you have that the majority of the information is redundant, and it feels weird to impose the downward closed condition. I figured I could kill two birds with one stone by using open simplices.

Comment: Enh, it is in some sense redundant since closed simplices are not pairwise disjoint, but then again the collection of closed simplices has some very nice and conceptually simple properties (e.g. the intersection of any two closed simplices is a closed simplex). Sometimes I don't like to let redundance get in the way of simplicity.